# Adding unrelated operator == renderers spaceship operator(<=>) non-functional

Tags: c++, spaceship-operator

In this code example, it seems that adding unreleated operator== (on a different type) renders the shaceship opreator not functional. This is tested in VS2019. Is it a compiler bug, or some weird behaviour?

```
class A
{
public:
  int x;
};

class B
{
public:
  constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const B& other) const = default;
  constexpr bool operator==(const A& other) const { return this->x == other.x; } // remove this so it can compile
  int x;
};

class C
{
public:
  constexpr operator bool() const { return b1 == b2; }
  B b1, b2;
};
```

The error I get is in the usage of the operator in the class B is:

binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const B' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Your definition of `==` takes an `A`, rather than a `B`.

Comment: Yes, that is the point.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to cppreference's [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) on how defaulted comparison operators work, let's examine what's happening.

For the first case, with no user-declared `operator==`:

```cpp
class B
{
public:
  constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const B& other) const = default;
  int x;
};
```

The following applies:

> If `operator<=>` is defaulted and `operator==` is not declared at all, then `operator==` is implicitly defaulted.

The default signature for `operator==` is `bool operator==(const B& other) const`. All well and good.

---

In your second version, you *do* declare an `operator==`. This means you *do not* get the defaulted `operator==` as a side-effect of defaulting `operator<=>`.

```cpp
class B
{
public:
  constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const B& other) const = default;
  constexpr bool operator==(const A& other) const { return this->x == other.x; }
  // No additional `operator==` will be generated aside from the above
  int x;
};
```

The problem is that the `operator==` you declared takes a `const A&` as the right hand side, instead of a `const B&`. So you cannot use this `operator==` to perform a check of the form `b1 == b2`.

---

If you want to have both the `operator==(const A&) const` overload and the default `operator==(const B&) const` overload, you can explicitly request that the latter be defaulted, like so:

```cpp
class B
{
public:
  constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const B& other) const = default;
  constexpr bool operator==(const B& other) const = default; 
  // Explicitly request default operator== as well as default operator<=>
  constexpr bool operator==(const A& other) const { return this->x == other.x; }

  int x;
};
```

Comment: So, it is basically yet another bug in the C++ standard. How could anyone define it this way, instead of the operator== having to have the proper signature?

Comment: What if you want to be able to compare a `B` with an `A`? Why should C++ stop you from doing so? There's all kinds of things where being able to perform an equality comparison between different classes. For instance equality comparison between a `std::string` and a `const char*` string literal. There's no reason for C++ to forbid an `operator==` with that signature. So there's just the thing where _if_ you declare it yourself, it disables implicit generation of another function that would be in the same overload set. Which is annoying, but crops up a few places

Comment: It's the same behavior you get with, say, assignment operators and special constructors.

Comment: Exactly, but comparing B with A shouldn't interfere with the A <=> A operator, as B and A are unrelated types. This is why I would go so far, as to say, that the C++ standard comittee is doing a poor job.

Comment: It didn't interfere with the `B <=> B` operator. Declaring a new `operator==` interfered with the default-generated `operator==`. If you changed `C::operator bool()` to use `return (b1 <=> b2) == 0;` instead, you don't need `B::operator==(const B&) const`.

Comment: Default-generated operator for a different type. So again, defaultly generated operator got cancled because of unrelated operator on a different type. There is some similar weirndess when it comes to virtual methods having the same name, but different signature.